# Table Grouping Column Change Based on Which Slicers Are Selected

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table similar to below.

[image: Table Data]

I also have 3 slicers: Supervisor Name, Manager Name, and Director Name.  Each slicer only accepts single values or 'All'.  What I'm trying to figure out is a way to make my table viz display SUM of LATES, but the grouping can change.  I need it to take the LOWEST hierarchical slicer with a value selected, and show SUM(LATES) for the grouping of the next level down.

So, if Supervisor has a value selected, it would show SUM(LATES) by employee.  If Supervisor was 'All' but Manager had a value selected, it would show SUM(LATES) by supervisor, etc.

I tried a grouping field with DAX like this, but it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

`FILTERED_NAME =  IF(CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('EMPLOYEE'[SUP_NAME]) , ALLSELECTED()) = TRUE(), 'EMPLOYEE'[EMP_NAME], IF(CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('EMPLOYEE'[MGR_NAME]) , ALLSELECTED()) = TRUE(), 'EMPLOYEE'[SUP_NAME], IF(CALCULATE(ISFILTERED('EMPLOYEE'[DIR_NAME]) , ALLSELECTED()) = TRUE(), 'EMPLOYEE'[MGR_NAME], 'EMPLOYEE'[DIR_NAME] )))`